# Install Discord.py on a Linux Python 3.8.5

Tags: python-3.x, linux, discord, discord.py, armbian

I recently installed armbian focal to a tinker board, and was attempting to install the discord python package. It's running a pre installed python 3.8.5 version, but I've only seen errors with installing the discord package when the python version is 3.9. I've also successfully installed the discord package on windows python 3.8.7, which means there is some difference I'm not aware of between windows python 3.8 and linux python 3.8, or I'm just missing some package to help me install discord.py, possibly because it was preinstalled (lightweight).

I can see that the program "Could not build wheels for multidict or yarl" but I'm not sure how to go about fixing the problem. I have searched for various versions of this question, but I only found people using python 3.9 which is a known error.

Here is the full output from the attempted install, the error makes up most of it. Has anyone else run into the same problem? I'd love some guidance on how to successfully install discord.py.

````
Collecting discord
  Using cached discord-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
Collecting discord.py>=1.0.1
  Using cached discord.py-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (701 kB)
Processing /root/.cache/pip/wheels/2d/6d/bb/486f8c893f1dcc917860a5b3e2f2ca286c398f7d548ffc649c/aiohttp-3.6.3-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.0.1->discord) (3.0.4)
Collecting multidict<5.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-4.7.6.tar.gz (50 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.5.1.tar.gz (173 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.0.1->discord) (2.8)
Building wheels for collected packages: multidict, yarl
  Building wheel for multidict (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpkkp4jqll build_wheel /tmp/tmpfgkdfx0m
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-j7e2t_uk/multidict
  Complete output (47 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/_multidict_py.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/_multidict_base.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/_abc.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying multidict/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/_multidict.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict
  copying multidict/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/defs.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/dict.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/istr.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/iter.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/pair_list.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  copying multidict/_multilib/views.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict/_multilib
  running build_ext
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c multidict/_multidict.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/multidict/_multidict.o -O2 -std=c99 -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wconversion -fno-strict-aliasing -pedantic
  multidict/_multidict.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
      1 | #include "Python.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
  Building wheel for yarl (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmps5xafkze build_wheel /tmp/tmp_pdfqzao
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-j7e2t_uk/yarl
  Complete output (42 lines):
  **********************
  * Accellerated build *
  **********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_url.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_quoting_py.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_quoting.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl
  running egg_info
  writing yarl.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to yarl.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl/*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying yarl/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_quoting_c.c -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_quoting_c.pyi -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/_quoting_c.pyx -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl
  copying yarl/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl
  running build_ext
  building 'yarl._quoting_c' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c yarl/_quoting_c.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.8/yarl/_quoting_c.o
  yarl/_quoting_c.c:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
      4 | #include "Python.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly```
````

Comment: Do you have the package `python3-dev` installed?

Comment: @CoderCharmander Thank you! After I installed python3-dev with `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` I was able to install the discord package with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the `python3-dev` package, which was not included in armbian's preinstalled python.

To install the `python3-dev` package, simply run:

`sudo apt install python3-dev`

Thanks to [@CoderCharmander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9211949/codercharmander)!